# Django - post request body additional data from drf serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need user to send me data in this format. Each items in the "data", mast contain "mandatory_key" and they can additionally send any other keys they want.

```
{
    "data": [
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... },
        { "mandatory_key": "Value", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2", "key_3": "value_3", ... }
    ]
}
```

since "mandatory_key" is the only key that I know, I can make my serializer like this.

```
class MySerializer(Serializer):
    mandatory_key = CharField()
```

When I initiate this serializer with data attribute, in the validated_data, it only gives me `mandatory_key`, not other keys.

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    print(serializer.validated_data)
```

Is there any ways I can do this using serializer? I don't want to manually validate it. Because the use case is much different.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to use a custom create () or update() in your serializer, then you can find the extra fields by accessing context data. For example, you can get all the available fiels by doing this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
   fields = self.context["request"].data
```

You will then get an object that shows all fields that were sent from the request. You can not get the data from the extra fields from the validate_data object because they are not part of your serializer, so they cannot be automatically validated

Answer (score 0):

Since one key that you're receiving is mandatory and rest could be blank=True and null=True in the model, you can just do the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

This should work but please make sure other modelfields are not mandatory when you define them inside the model

Comment: I'm not using a ModelSerializer. And I don't know which keys the user'll send, the keys can be anything. so I can't predefine them.